# How to synchronize a signal receiver clock?

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

Let's say I'm receiving a binary signal digitally, where the logical "1" is transmitted as the presence of the signal, and the logical "0" transmitted is the absence of the signal.

The time duration of the logical "1" is the same as the logical "0", but the transmitter clock can drift, differing the 1 or 0 durations slightly. There is a maximum amount of consecutive 1 or 0 that can be transmitted.

In computer programming code, what is the general algorithm to do that? How do I synchronize the receiver clock to adapt the drifts? What should be the minimum sampling rate of the signal?

Comment: The signal is digital in value (it is 0 or 1, not 0.9, etc) but continous in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the communication systems use (up down) and (down up) for 0 and 1. That is from 0 to t/2 signal is up and from t/2 to t signal is down for 0 (and vice versa for 1) where t is the period of signal. Using this strategy should eliminate your problem.

Edit: See this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-clocking_signal

Answer (score 0):

Normally timing is recovered from a run-length-limited NRZ encoded signal by means of a phase locked loop (PLL) that is being fed the timings of all the transitions.

If you are sampling the signal instead of using transition times, then the higher the sample rate the less jitter there will be in the PLL frequency.  But in any case, the sample rate needs to be clearly faster than 2 times the reciprocal of the bit time.

You might want to ask this question in the [signal processing site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing something that seems to be very similar to [RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232).

The way the clock is synchronized there is by first making sure that both ends are running at the same frequency (baud rate) and then define a start and stop sequence for every set number of bits. So, for example, you will send a 0 as the start bit and a 1 as a stop bit, and then a whole bunch of bits in between (a byte, say). Since your two clocks are almost the same, all you have to do to synchronise the signals is look in the stop/start bit for a 1 to zero transition, and that will signal the start of a new word.

That way you reset the error between your clocks to zero every so many bits, making sure it doesn't accumulate and cause problems. The Wikipedia page on [asynchronous serial communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_start-stop) talks about what I just said in a lot more detail.